View PDF file that is saved in Google Drive using Google App Script on Google Sheets
I have Google Sheet with google app script that is created with the help of ChatGPT. It made a code that creates a PDF file from the selected range, sets the filename and then save it in the "My Drive". I want a code to be able to view the saved PDF file but the code by ChatGPT, there is "drive.google.com refused to connect." displayed inside the modal dialog.
here is the code that it gave:
function viewPDF() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var certificateSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Certificate");
  
  // Define the filename
  var filename = certificateSheet.getRange("D4").getValue() + "_" + certificateSheet.getRange("B6").getValue() + "_" + certificateSheet.getRange("D6").getValue() + ".pdf";

  // Search for the PDF file in "My Drive"
  var folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var files = folder.getFilesByName(filename);

  // If the file exists, get the first matching file
  if (files.hasNext()) {
    var pdfFile = files.next();
    
    // Get the URL of the PDF file
    var pdfUrl = pdfFile.getUrl();
    
    // Check if the URL is in the direct link format
    if (pdfUrl.includes('/file/d/')) {
      // Convert the URL to the Google Drive PDF viewer format
      var fileId = pdfUrl.match(/\/file\/d\/(.+?)\//)[1];
      pdfUrl = 'https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=https://drive.google.com/file/d/' + fileId + '/view?usp=drive_link';
    }

    // Create HTML content for modal dialog
    var html = '<iframe src="' + pdfUrl + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>';

    // Create a modal dialog
    var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
      .setWidth(800)
      .setHeight(600);

    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, "PDF Viewer");
  } else {
    // If the file does not exist, display an error message
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("PDF file not found.");
  }
}

I tried other AI sites but the code that the chatGPT gave was the closest to what I want.

From your showing script and error message, I'm worried that the following modification points.
Modification points:

I'm worried that your URL of url=https://drive.google.com/file/d/' + fileId + '/view?usp=drive_link might not be able to be used in this situation.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?
Modified script 1:
In this modification, the PDF URL is used from this official document.
function viewPDF() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var certificateSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Certificate");
  var filename = certificateSheet.getRange("D4").getValue() + "_" + certificateSheet.getRange("B6").getValue() + "_" + certificateSheet.getRange("D6").getValue() + ".pdf";
  var folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var files = folder.getFilesByName(filename);
  if (files.hasNext()) {
    var pdfFile = files.next();
    // pdfFile.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW); // If an error related to the permission occurred, please use this line.
    var pdfUrl = pdfFile.getUrl();
    if (pdfUrl.includes('/file/d/')) {
      var fileId = pdfFile.getId();
      pdfUrl = `<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/${fileId}/preview" width="100%" height="100%" allow="autoplay"></iframe>`;
    }
    var html = `<html><style>html,body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }</style><body>${pdfUrl}</body></html>`;
    var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(800).setHeight(600);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, "PDF Viewer");
  } else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("PDF file not found.");
  }
}


In this case, it seems that the PDF file is not required to be publicly shared. But, if an error related to the permission occurred, please use the above comment line.

When this script is run, the following result is obtained.



Modified script 2:
In this modification, the PDF URL is used from this thread.
function viewPDF() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var certificateSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Certificate");
  var filename = certificateSheet.getRange("D4").getValue() + "_" + certificateSheet.getRange("B6").getValue() + "_" + certificateSheet.getRange("D6").getValue() + ".pdf";
  var folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var files = folder.getFilesByName(filename);
  if (files.hasNext()) {
    var pdfFile = files.next();
    pdfFile.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
    var pdfUrl = pdfFile.getUrl();
    if (pdfUrl.includes('/file/d/')) {
      var fileId = pdfFile.getId();
      pdfUrl = `https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=https://drive.usercontent.google.com/download?id=${fileId}&confirm=xxx`;
    }
    var html = `<html><style>html,body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }</style><body><iframe src="${pdfUrl}" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe></body></html>`;
    var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(800).setHeight(600);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, "PDF Viewer");
  } else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("PDF file not found.");
  }
}


In this case, it seems that the PDF file is required to be publicly shared.


thank you for your reply sir Tanaike, the codes that you provided works but is there a way to also have a print button on the viewer like when you view a PDF file in a browser?

@Angelei Thank you for replying. From the codes that you provided works, I understood that your question, that you wanted to remove the error of drive.google.com refused to connect., was resolved. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

@Angelei About your new question of is there a way to also have a print button on the viewer like when you view a PDF file in a browser?, in this case, I think that it is required to click the pop out button at the top right button.
